# How to include limit for retrieving page likes by current user by using FB SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, xcode7

I had a little problem about how can I set the limit when requesting page likes by current user using FB SDK for iOS. Whenever I tried the request it returns 25 result of FB pages instead of limit it by one.

this is my code for requesting FB page likes by current user :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hLqT.png

I think my code is correct, because I tried it before in FB Graph Explorer tools, it's working perfect. Here is what I did in FB Graph Explorer :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO2bj.png

Anyone have any idea how can I fix this little problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you may be helped

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
    initWithGraphPath:@"/me/likes"
           parameters:@{ @"fields": @"about,name,created_time",@"limit": @"1",}
           HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
{

// here you got a one result from this code
  NSLOG("%@",result);

}];
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. But can I know why does my code doesn't work?

Comment: i think you forgot  { } in parameters..plz upvote in my answer.